# Python-3.x: while using the following code i got an error as "object has no attribute 'split "'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input())
arr = [int(x) for x in input.split()]
```

this is the code i used. I  want  to  get list of input from  the user
but i am getting error as

```
    arr = [int(x) for x in input.split()]
    AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: thank you for  the help but i  solve  it out as i have noticed i left parenthesis for input

Comment: please Close this question by accepting some answer or answering it yourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to split the input function itself, and not its results. You need to split the string it returns, like this `input().split()`. Mind you that this will not do anything because split has no parameters. It'll simply return a list with the user's input as the sole parameter. If you want to divide the input string into its chars, you can simply use `list(input())`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling split on the builtin function `input`. While what you should be doing is calling it on the `n` variable. So it should look like this

```
n = int(input()) 
arr = [int(x) for x in n.split()] # Still wrong
```

But still let me quote that `int` however has no split attribute. So make sure it is a String type.

So your try not to convert your input into `int` until you process the value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are going for, turn the input to a list and ints for items in the list

```
  l = [int(i) for i in list(input('Enter number: '))]
```

> ```
> Enter number: 101
> [1, 0, 1]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As Vineeth said, you are trying to call split on input. Also, you can't split an integer since split is a method that can only be used on strings, so you shouldn't cast n as an integer.

```
n = str(input())
arr = [int(x) for x in n.split()]
```